# Dojox.Mobile.ComboBox does not respond to selection on Android

Tags: javascript, events, combobox, dojo, dojox.mobile

I have developed a mobile web app using Dojox Mobile.  One of my views contains several `dojox.mobile.ComboBox` controls that open the drop down as expected upon being clicked, but will not respond when I tap an entry in the drop down to select it.  The drop down menu just stays open.

I am using `Android version 4.1.2` on a `Droid RAZR MAXX HD` with `Chrome version 26.0.1410.58`.

The app is using the `ESRI JavaScript API v3.4compact` which includes `dojo v1.8`

Has anyone else experienced this?  Is there a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried `dojox/mobile/tests/test_ComboBox.html` on `Galaxy S3` `Android 4.1.2` using `Dojo 1.8.3`, and I did reproduce the issue you encountered with both Chrome and the platform browser.

On the other side, with both browsers it seems to work using the `Dojo 1.9.0 rc2` (http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.0rc2/). So for now I would recommend upgrading to `Dojo 1.9` if possible in your context.

If upgrading is not an option for you, I'd suggest that you open a ticket at http://trac.dojotoolkit.org.

Side-remark, `dojox/mobile/ComboBox` is flagged "experimental".

Comment: @Brian Are you able to solve this issue by upgrading Dojo to 1.9.0? I'm still facing the issue. Can you help?

Comment: I tried to upgrade the same but still facing the same issue. I'm running my application on Android Lollipop (5.0). Any suggestion?